# Identifying synonymous rows of a text column in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, sentence-similarity, pattern-synonyms

Suppose ABC is a dataframe as given below:

```
ABC <- data.frame(Column1 = c(1.222, 3.445, 5.621, 8.501, 9.302), 
                  Column2 = c(654231, 12347, -2365, 90000, 12897), 
                  Column3 = c('A1', 'B2', 'E3', 'C1', 'F5'), 
                  Column4 = c('I bought it', 'The flower has a beautiful fragrance', 'It was bought by me', 'I have bought it', 'The flower smells good'), 
                  Column5 = c('Good', 'Bad', 'Ok', 'Moderate', 'Perfect'))
```

My intention is to find synonymous strings in Column4. In this case, **I bought it**, **It was bought by me** and **I have bought it** are synonymous or similar strings and **The flower has a beautiful fragrance** and **The flower smells good** convey similar meaning.

I tried the approach of **IVR** in the following thread and got stuck: [Find similar texts based on paraphrase detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206048/find-similar-texts-based-on-paraphrase-detection/21371010?noredirect=1#comment116135875_21371010)

When I run the HLS.Extract code chunk, I get the following error message:

```
Error in strsplit(PlainTextDocument(synonyms(word)), ",") : non-character Argument
```

Using as.character didn't resolve the problem either:

```
Syns = function(word){  
    word <- as.character(word) ###
    wl    =   gsub("(.*[[:space:]].*)","",      
                   gsub("^c\\(|[[:punct:]]+|^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$","",  
                        unlist(strsplit(PlainTextDocument(synonyms(word)),","))))
    wl = wl[wl!=""] 
    return(wl)     
  }
```

1. What is going wrong?
2. Is there a better way to code it using R, and create a new column additionally which has, say a number 1 as an entry for the first synonymous strings and 2 as the entry for the next set of synonymous strings?
3. Does it work with German text?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by setting PlainTextDocument(synonyms(word)) as character, as shown below:

```
Syns = function(word){ 
    wl    =   gsub("(.*[[:space:]].*)","",      
                   gsub("^c\\(|[[:punct:]]+|^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$","",  
                        unlist(strsplit(as.character(PlainTextDocument(synonyms(word))),",")))) 
    wl = wl[wl!=""] 
    return(wl)     
  }
```