# Extract product name from english text

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, nlp

I want extract the names of products being sold from English text.

For example:

> "I'm selling my xbox brand new"
>
> "Selling rarely used 27 inch TV"

Should give me `"xbox"` and `"27 inch TV"`

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to hardcode in a giant list of important nouns and important adjectives: `['tv', 'fridge', 'xbox', 'laptop', etc]`

Is there a better approach?

Comment: [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) isn't easy.

Comment: Seriously lanzz? Is the point of this site not to ask questions even when you have no clue where to start? Are algorithmic questions against the rules?

Comment: Unfortunately, "no clue where to start" is often also, pretty much by definition, too broad, andea recommendation question. [Quick googling](https://google.com/search?q=text+extract+product-names) should reveal that this is still a research problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text mining - extract name of band from unstructured text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670498/text-mining-extract-name-of-band-from-unstructured-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like nltk will give you a list of words and their parts of speech.  Since you are only interested in nouns? [this](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tag.html) will provide you with them

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad.")) 
[('John', 'NNP'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('big', 'JJ'), ('idea', 'NN'), ('is',
'VBZ'), ("n't", 'RB'), ('all', 'DT'), ('that', 'DT'), ('bad', 'JJ'),
('.', '.')]
```