# How to check whether a pattern contain multiple words present in a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I am working on an java and MySQL based application and i have task to check whether set of adjacent words present in a given string contains a lot of words.
For example

The string is

```
" java is a programing language .java is robust and powerful and it is also platform independent. "
```

I want to check whether the substrings

```
"programing language"
```

```
"platform independent"
```

and

```
"robust and powerful"
```

present in the above string. The substring also must match even if more than one white space occur between the words.

Comment: Do you know the sub strings to search before hand ?

Comment: "*check whether set of adjacent words present in a given string contains a lot of words.*" What?

Comment: You are interested in phrases rather than words. This is not as simple as finding words. This link can be of some use to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643616/algorithms-to-detect-phrases-and-keywords-from-text

Comment: yes I tried it by using indexOf method in java which return -1 if pattern does not found. But main problem of that approach is it is not efficient  when you want to check more than 100 patterns in 100 sentences , That is why I ask this question to find out most efficient method for pattern matching in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
String string = " java is a programing language .java is robust and powerful and it is also platform independent. ";

String subS1 = "programing language";
subS1 = subS1.replace(" ", "\\s+");
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(subS1);
Matcher match1 = string.matcher(subS1);

String subS2 = "platform independent";
subS2 = subS2.replace(" ", "\\s+");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(subS2);
Matcher match2 = string.matcher(subS2);

String subS3 = "robust and powerful";
subS3 = subS3.replace(" ", "\\s+");
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile(subS3);
Matcher match3 = string.matcher(subS3);

if (match1.find() && match2.find() && match3.find()) {
  // Whatever you like
}
```

You should replace all spaces in the substrings with '\s+', so it will also find "programing  [loads of whitespaces] language".
Then compile the pattern you want to find and match the string and the substring. Repeat for each substring. 
Lastly, test whether the matchers found anything.

**Some Notes**

- Didn't test it, but it should give an idea of how I should do it.
- Also, this should give an answer to you very specific question. This method should *not* be used when you have a large amount of substrings to check...
- Please post some code you were already working with, because now I feel like making your homework...

Comment: Can you say which method should I use if I have a large amount of substring to check. I have to analyse more than 100 tuple sets in employee table and I have about 100 pattern to check in these 100 tuples . So is the above method is efficient or can you suggest some better ways.

Comment: @GeordyJames, you better start a new question with exact information about what you need, since this new question is quite different from the one I answered. What tuple sets? Do you have some code you already started with? In the new question, please give examples of (i) a substring, (ii) a tuple set, (iii) a pattern, (iv) what your program should do (the result) and (v) what you already coded.
I do not think that I, and the others that commented, understand your question well enough to give a useful answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for the first part of your question, I don't if I did not miss understand your question.

```
    String str  = " java is a programing language .java is robust and powerful and it is also platform independent. ";
    if (str.contains("programing language")) {
         System.out.println("programing language");
    }
    if (str.contains("platform independent")) {
         System.out.println("platform independent");
    }
    if (str.contains("robust and powerful")) {
        System.out.println("robust and powerful");
    }
```

I don't know what do you mean by this: *The substring also must match even if more than one white space occur between the words.*